# Extract a field from JSOn, using Native javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Can someone please assist me in extracting the Sring from `translatedText`

```
{
    "data":{
        "translations":[
            {
                "translatedText":"நான் Google மொழிபெயர்ப்பாளர் இருந்து JSON பதில் சோதனை"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**My Code:**

```
<head>
<script>
var xmlHttp = null;

function GetCustomerInfo()
{
    var CustomerNumber = document.getElementById( "sourceText" ).value;
    alert(CustomerNumber);
    var myKey = 'ttes';
    var Url = "https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key="+ myKey + "&source=en&target=ta&q=" + CustomerNumber + "&prettyprint=true"

    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = ProcessRequest;
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", Url, true );
    xmlHttp.send( null );
}

function ProcessRequest() 
{
    if ( xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200 || xmlHttp.status == 304) 
    {
        if ( xmlHttp.responseText == "Not found" ) 
        {
            document.getElementById( "TextBoxCustomerName"    ).value = "Not found";
            document.getElementById( "TextBoxCustomerAddress" ).value = "";
        }
        else
        {
            var info = eval ( '(' + xmlHttp.responseText + ')' );

            // No parsing necessary with JSON!        
            document.getElementById( "translatedText" ).innerHTML = info.data[0].translations[0].translatedText;
        }                    
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="sourceText"/>
<button onclick="GetCustomerInfo()">Translate Me</button>
<br>
<div id="translatedText">
</div>
</body>
```

But `translatedText` is empty always!

Comment: @dystroy I have a div named `translatedText`

Comment: And with that edit, you've rendered all the answers obsolete. Consider posting all the relevant information right away, and don't put the solutions below into your question.

Comment: @cookiemonster Sorry, I was trying one of the answers and posted..!

Comment: Consider some basic debugging steps, like logging the various values to the developer console, and checking for errors.

Comment: Two things: 1) you don't need the [0] after info.data... check my response below 2) make sure you dont get this: {"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"usageLimits","reason":"keyInvalid","message":"BadRequest"}],"code":400,"message":"BadRequest"}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
var info = eval ( '(' + xmlHttp.responseText + ')' );
```

Yeah, and also

```
info.data.translations[0]...
```

insread of

```
info.data[0].translations[0]...
```

Comment: Don't use `eval`. `eval` is Evil. use `JSON.parse` instead

Comment: Mindlessly parroting the "eval is evil" mantra isn't useful. This answer correctly shows the two issues in the code. +1 Though I'd personally prefer `JSON.parse` in this situation.

Comment: It worked, my mistake was accessing `data[0]` as you pointed

Answer (score 2):

```
var info = JSON.parse(responseText);    
var translation = info.data.translations[0].translatedText
```

Answer (score 1):

```
JSON.parse('{ "data": { "translations": [ { "translatedText": "நான் Google மொழிபெயர்ப்பாளர் இருந்து JSON பதில் சோதனை" } ] } }')['data']['translations'][0]['translatedText'];
```

or

```
JSON.parse('{ "data": { "translations": [ { "translatedText": "நான் Google மொழிபெயர்ப்பாளர் இருந்து JSON பதில் சோதனை" } ] } }').data.translations[0].translatedText;
```

Comment: I get the text, but unfortunately, I dont get it the exact language!

Comment: Worked if I send the JSON variable as such! Instead of the String..

Answer (score 0):

Try JSON.parse:

```
var myObject = JSON.parse(myJSONtext);
```

then u can use myObject to retrieve object properties.